# SQL - Problema ao Nomear variaveis

Tags: sql, variáveis

Como não sei explicar bem o meu problema, vou dar um exemplo:

```
select cod_prod, sum(quantidade) as "Quantidade 2013", sum(quantidade) as "Quantidade 2014"
from itens
group by cod_prod
having "Quantidade 2013" in ...
```

O exemplo a cima não está a funcionar porque ele não reconhece o nome "Quantidade 2013".

A minha dúvida é:

Como é que eu arranjo uma forma de diferenciar um sum(quantidade) do outro de forma a que eu consiga manipulá-los de forma distinta no método having?

Detalhes:

[image: Diagrama]
[image: Pergunta]

Comment: Talvez seja o caso do uso de CASE , sem trocadilho , para tratar o ano 20xx

Comment: @Motta provavelmente um case 2013 soma o campo, ou zero, mas ai vem o problema do having, pois dependendo do DB ele pode usar alias, dependendo do DB tem que repetir a fórmula. Seria importante ele [edit] e acrescentar os detalhes

Comment: @Motta acrescentei novos detalhes para ajudar na compreensão do problema

Comment: @Bacco acrescentei novos detalhes para ajudar na compreensão do problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara, nesse caso, eu diria pra você fazer as somas separadamente, e então cruzar com os resultados que você tem na sua seleção principal.

Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
select cod_prod, s1.quantidade_soma as "Quantidade 2013", s1.quantidade_soma as "Quantidade 2014"
from itens i
join ( /*seleção em que você passará o ano e o código do produto*/
        select cod_prod, sum(quantidade) as quantidade_soma, 
        from itens i1
        where to_char(data_enc,'YYYY') = '2014'
        group by cod_prod
) s1 on (s1.cod_prod = i.cod_prod) 
/* repetir para 2013*/
where s1.quantidade_soma > s2.quantidade_soma
```

Eu diria ainda pra você primeiro filtrar, e no lugar do `from itens i` principal, já trazer os dados que ele pede no enunciado.

Qualquer dúvida, é só falar.

Comment: Entendi, obrigadão ;)